# PHP preg_match_all + str_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match-all, str-replace

I need to find a way to replace all the <p> within all the <blockquote> before the <hr />.

Here's a sample html:

```
<p>2012/01/03</p>
<blockquote>
    <h4>File name</h4>
    <p>Good Game</p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote><p>Laurie Ipsumam</p></blockquote>
<h4>Some title</h4>
<hr />
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<blockquote><p>Laurel Ipsucandescent</p></blockquote>
```

Here's what I got:

```
    $pieces = explode("<hr", $theHTML, 2);
    $blocks = preg_match_all('/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/s', $pieces[0], $blockmatch); 

    if ($blocks) { 
        $t1=$blockmatch[1];
        for ($j=0;$j<$blocks;$j++) {
            $paragraphs = preg_match_all('/<p>/', $t1[$j], $paragraphmatch);
            if ($paragraphs) {
                $t2=$paragraphmatch[0]; 
                for ($k=0;$k<$paragraphs;$k++) { 
                    $t1[$j]=str_replace($t2[$k],'<p class=\"whatever\">',$t1[$j]);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

I think I'm really close, but I don't know how to put back together the html that I just pieced out and modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `simple_xml`, or better `DOMDocument` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) before you  make it a valid html code, and use this functionality to find the nodes you are looking for, and replace them, for this you could try `XPath` (http://w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).

Edit 1:

Take a look at the answer of this question:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to do is correct thousands of entries in a MySQLdatabase/Drupal that all start in this same pattern. My logic was to use php to get all the entries and replace all the tags by first ridding all the <h4> and inline styling, then add a class to all the <p> in the blockquotes, and finally removing the blockquotes. I made it work with the code below by adding a while(preg_match) but there is still the case that if there's a <blockquote> with no <p> in it. Only happens in a couple hundred cases but still happens. I'll take a look at your solutions and hopefully find something.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = explode('<hr', $string);
$string[0] = preg_replace('/<blockquote>(.*)<p>(.*)<\/p>(.*)<\/blockquote>/sU', '<blockquote>\1<p class="whatever">\2</p>\3</blockquote>', $string[0]);
$string = $string[0] . '<hr' . $string[1];
```

output:

```
<p>2012/01/03</p>
<blockquote>
    <h4>File name</h4>
    <p class="whatever">Good Game</p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote><p class="whatever">Laurie Ipsumam</p></blockquote>
<h4>Some title</h4>
<hr />
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<blockquote><p>Laurel Ipsucandescent</p></blockquote>
```

Comment: blast, just noticed that didn't get the first <p> tag.

Comment: you do have an ugly regex, maybe it is not such a good idea to teach people that regex can be used to parse html, even if in this particular case it might work

Comment: Yeah. It won't work if there's more than one <p> tag in a <blockquote>. The complexity grows too quickly.

Comment: I had made it work with a while(preg_match) to just repeat the code you gave, but now I need to find a way to add a <p class="whatever> to any <blockquote> that have no <p> inside. I'm thinking regex wasn't made for all this trouble but I'm not exactly sure what type of solution I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "add a <p class="whatever> to any <blockquote> that have no <p> inside". Do you mean that `<blockquote>something</blockquote>` should become `<blockquote><p class="whatever">something</p></blockquote>`?

Comment: That's pretty much it. But I think I should do a number more tutorials on regex and alternative solutions before continuing, I really wouldn't want to make things worse with all these pages.